# What are the concrete demands of Germans who want to "put an end to" (Schlussstrich ziehen) nazi commemorations?

Tags: germany, history, nazism

The head of the German nationalist party *Alternative für Deutschland (AFD)* has demanded *einen Schlussstrich unter Deutschlands Nazi-Vergangenheit*, which in English translates more or less as *to put an end to Germans Nazi past*.  I don't understand what this means in practice, but a large majority of their voters support this.  For example, see [Der Spiegel](https://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/alexander-gauland-provoziert-mit-rede-zu-deutschlands-nazi-vergangenheit-a-1167750.html), [Neues Deutschland](https://www.neues-deutschland.de/artikel/1091312.geschichtspolitik-der-afd-der-schlussstrich-hilft-dem-ressentiment.html), [Migazin](https://www.migazin.de/2020/01/27/umfrage-drei-afd-anhaengern-schlussstrich/), or the [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/01/18/world/europe/germany-afd-alternative-bjorn-hocke.html).  But what would this mean concretely?  Do they propose to stop covering nazi crimes in history education?  To move or dismantle commemoration sites?  To stop prosecuting nazis (demographics will ensure the latter soon enough anyway)?  Or is it just a rhetorical remark, reclaiming the moral right to call to "Make Germany Great Again" without concerning oneself with the Holocaust?

Comment: Do you have a reason to assume that there is such a list of demands? I would assume that having a list of such demands would be counter-productive to the AFD, as people can then disagree about the items on the list. A vague notion can find far more supporters.

Comment: They don't want to talk about Nazism because it highlights the negative aspects of who they are.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Schlussstrichdebatte](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlussstrichdebatte) isn't something new the AFD picked up recently, it started right after WW2. Here is for example a poster by the FDP from 1949:

[image: FDP poster "Schluss mit Entnazifizierung"]

The first demand was to stop [denazification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denazification) (the denazification program was already weak in the late 40s and stopped by the early 50s).

But in general, the Schlussstrichdebatte is much less about specific actionable items, and instead about the form of social debate ("gesellschaftliche Debatte") and German identity. Franz-Josef Strauß expressed this when he said he didn't 'want to hear from Auschwitz anymore' or Ernst Nolte, who didn't want to hear about the 'responsibility of the Germans' ("Schuld der Deutschen").

Regarding [Erinnerungskultur](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erinnerungskultur), the desire is to stop focusing on German crimes and to instead commemorate those responsible for the Holocaust and put blame on those who fought against fascism (see [eg](https://www.welt.de/politik/deutschland/article161286915/Was-Hoecke-mit-der-Denkmal-der-Schande-Rede-bezweckt.html) Höckes comments about a "Denkmal der Schande" and a desire for a "erinnerungspolitische Wende um 180 Grad", the focus on Dresden, the accusation that the allied forces tried to take Germans collective identity, Gauland who wants to be [proud](https://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/alexander-gauland-provoziert-mit-rede-zu-deutschlands-nazi-vergangenheit-a-1167750.html) of the performance of German soldiers in two world wars etc).

Some more concrete demands are eg against building of new memorial sites (see eg this example about [signs informing about historical events related to WW2](https://daserste.ndr.de/panorama/archiv/2018/Holocaust-Wie-die-AfD-die-Schuld-beenden-will,erinnerungskultur106.html))

Comment: Something about "Fliegenschiss" could be incorporated

Comment: I really struggle to understand why this gets downvotes.

Comment: @Arno Just speculating, but *perhaps* some current FDP supporters (if this species hasn't gone extinct yet) are unhappy to be reminded that once upon a time, FDP was demanding a *schlussstrich*, where today this demand is only heard from the extreme-right (for context, FDP is a pro-business small-government liberalism party which is right-wing, but moderately so, perhaps like the Lib.-Dems in the UK or the Democratic Party in the US).

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I thought it was *Vogelschiss*, which admittedly is a little bit worse than *Fliegenschiss*.

Comment: It might be helpful to include an English translation of the poster.  ("The bottom line!  No more denazification, disenfranchisement, incapacity.  No more second-class citizenship.  Who wants civil equality, vote FDP.")

Comment: @Arno Because it comes off as very Nazi apologetic. Thanks to the Soviets, west Germany got away with a lot of things. Complaining about bringing up their past is one of them.

Comment: @dan-klasson In my reading, tim has written in a completely neutral style. He obviously is quoting from Nazi-apologists, but that seems hardly avoidable when answering this question.

Comment: @dan-klasson Let me know what parts come off that way, and I'll see if I can clarify (that's most definitely not how the answer is intended). I wouldn't but the blame on the Soviets, but I agree that post-WW2, Germany did get away with way too much.

Comment: @Arno Yeah but he also doesn't mention who the FDP was, nor try to explain the history behind this revisionist movement. I'm not putting the blame on the Soviets. I'm saying the west looked the other way as their main enemy at that time, were the expanding influence of the Soviet Union.

Comment: @dan-klasson I agree with that. I picked up the FDP poster because it's a prominent example of early "schlussstrich" demands, but I think looking at the (highly questionable) history of the FDP or revisionism in-depth would be outside the scope of this question.